# How do I check which version of GDAL I have and how many?

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal, postgresql, osgeo4w

I have installed in my computer the following software:

- PosgresSQL 9.3.2.3
- PostGIS 2.1.1.1
- QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour (this one installed through the OSGeo4w package)
- QGIS 1.7.0 Wroclaw

As far as I know all of them somehow operate, or use, or access the GDAL library.

Are they independent versions of GDAL therefore being used depending on which one of the above software I am using? For instance, If I open the OSGeo4W Shell, just after loading the batch it displays:

`GDAL 1.10.1, released 2015/02/10`

So, how can I check the other GDAL versions and make comparisons?

Is there any way of centralize all of this stuff and force the apps to use the same centralized folder?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

OSGEO4W and all standalone QGIS installers come with a OSGEO4W Shell.

Start that, and type `gdalinfo --version` and read the result.

You may have different versions on the disk: Standalone, OSGEO4W and also from gisinternals if you want the latest GDAL build, but every package sets its environment so that it is using the version it was delivered with. Actually they don't know of each other.

That is the reason why you can not execute any GDAL exe or bat by just clicking on the file in Windows Explorer.

Comment: That's what I thought but I wasn't sure. So, I MUST have...3 or 4 versions of GDAL. Thanks.

Comment: "That is the reason why you can not execute any GDAL exe or bat by just clicking on the file in Windows Explorer." Could you elaborate exactly what you mean? Just because there are separate instances of gdal installed on a machine should not mean that their executables can not be executed from Windows explorer. And just because they need a certain environment to work does not mean that they can not be called from Explorer since Windows/Explorer also has an environment set up. But maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to point out?

Comment: The executables will only work as expected if the varables that are set by OSGEo4W.bat or SDKshell.bat are placed in the Windows environment. If you have different versions of GDAL installed, only one can be used in that way.

Answer (score 6):

PosgresSQL 9.3.2.3 shouldn't be using GDAL, since it is just a database without no dependencies on it.

PostGIS 2.1.1.1 doesn't [require the latest GDAL](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#install_requirements) (recommends at least 1.9), but if you installed it using OSGEO4W, then it is probably linked to the latest GDAL (1.10).

QGIS 2.0.1 is probably linked to GDAL 1.10.

QGIS 1.7 is probably linked to GDAL 1.8 or 1.9; unlikely it uses 1.10.

With QGIS, you can see the version of dependent libraries in the **About** dialog.

The [package listing for OSGeo4W is here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/PackageListing).

To see what each actual library or executable is linked to, on Windows you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).