# OSGEO4W Checking GDAL version with `gdalinfo --version` returns nothing

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w

I am using OSGEO4W 32-bit on Windows 10.  I am trying to check the version of GDAL. 
 Following [the instructions here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86296/how-do-i-check-which-version-of-gdal-i-have-and-how-many), when I input `gdalinfo --version` in the OSGEO4W shell, I get [just a blank line](https://i.gyazo.com/d7a9309d82dc6b79c0aee142dcbf39f0.png).

Why am I receiving just a blank line and not the version number?

Comment: Odd, just checked that it works for me but I have the 64-bit version of OsGeo4W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because a problem with your `gdal` version...

Run *osgeo4w-setup.exe*, located by default in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`.

Select *Advanced Setup* and follow. Select *Install from Internet* and follow.

Select your existing Root Directory and preferences until you reach the following screen:

[image: gdal]

Search for `gdal`, toggle to Full View. The first column will show you your installed version.

Comment: That works.  [What I see](https://i.gyazo.com/0e67fca85160e6a33529f64515e56dc5.png).  Not sure why using `gdalinfo --version` in the shell is not working for me.  In fact, none of the commands starting with `gdalinfo` works for me.

Comment: @Valachio, the `gdal` version is ok. Maybe you need install (toggle from Skip) the current (stable) version of `gdal-python` and `python3-gdal`just from [that screen](https://i.gyazo.com/0e67fca85160e6a33529f64515e56dc5.png), so that the commands work at the OSGeo4W Shell.