# Get version of installed QGIS from Windows command line

Tags: qgis

Tell me please, how can I get current version of installed QGIS from command line (batch-file). QGIS installed with Osgeo4w-installer.

Registry search did not return any result.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86296/how-do-i-check-which-version-of-gdal-i-have-and-how-many#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=OSGEO4W%20and%20all%20standalone%20QGIS,version%20and%20read%20the%20result.

Comment: Perhaps you should write a Python script and ask it directly from QGIS. See https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgis.html.

Comment: qgis --version
in the osgeo4w shell

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am not good enough with Windows batch files or Power shell scripts but I can show where the OSGeo4W installer is storing that info. It can be found from the temp directory that is used for caching the downloaded packages before installation. The location is by default something like

`C:\Users\SOME_USER\AppData\Local\Temp\http%3a%2f%2fdownload.osgeo.org%2fosgeo4w%2f\x86_64>`

The `http` part in the path name is the URL of the mirror that was used when the installer was run. The file to look at is `setup.ini` and it contains a section for each installed item.

```
@ qgis
sdesc: "QGIS Desktop"
ldesc: "QGIS Desktop"
category: Desktop
requires: qgis-common python3-core pyqt5 python3-gdal gpsbabel python3-psycopg2 python3-qscintilla python3-jinja2 python3-markupsafe python3-pygments python3-python-dateutil python3-pytz python3-future python3-requests python3-pyproj python3-pyyaml python3-plotly python3-owslib python3-httplib2 python3-nose2 python3-mock qt5-qml exiv2 qt5-tools
version: 3.14.16-2
install: x86_64/release/qgis/qgis/qgis-3.14.16-2.tar.bz2 49937472 b203a2993cff9783d3bb9565126a0700
[prev]
version: 3.14.16-1
install: x86_64/release/qgis/qgis/qgis-3.14.16-1.tar.bz2 49942698 14ef4259f23d1b67be8f82189d7e0b70
```

The challenge for the script-writers is simply "Find string `@ GIS`. It must be exact match to avoid lines like `@ qgis-dev`. Probably there are no white spaces on the line but I am not sure. Alternatively find `sdesc: "QGIS Desktop"`). The version is on the 6th line of the block.

I would love to see this solved with awk but unfortunately it does not come with Windows.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But here's my situation. I'm going to install QGIS using osgeo4w from dowloaded files to a shared folder on local network (not internet). And I want to check the version of the installed QGIS on computers before installing (updating).
I also cannot figure out how the last installed version of the program is launched when I click *.qgs- and *.qgz-files. I didn't see any mention in the environment variables, in the registry too.

Comment: OSGeo4W starts QGIS by running qgis.bat in the \bin directory. It runs whatever qgis-bin.exe that it finds from the search path. `@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
call qt5_env.bat
call py3_env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-bin.exe" %*`

Comment: Yes, I understand, how qgis starts of course. I dont understand, how qgis starts, when I doubleclick on project file file.qgs from desktop, for example. When I install 2 versions of qgis on the computer, how system understand, that it should be runned last installed version qgis. Where system hold variables for this.

Comment: Registry settings are in the directory c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin (on my computer), in file `qgis.req`.  There is a key `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QGIS Project\Shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\qgis.bat\" \"%1\""`. So QGIS project is opened with qgis.bat that starts the binary that has a fixed name and location `start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-bin.exe" %*`. And registry is edited with some post-install batch file magic. See qgis.bat.done that you have in OSGeo4W64\etc\postinstall. Keys seem to be for the ROOT user.

Comment: Thanks for help! I'm going to continue looking for a way to get the current version of qgis with the cmd :)

Comment: I am not sure if you can as it stands now but study the OSGeo4W batch files. You can make your users computers aware of the version for example by renaming qgis-bin.exe like qgis-bin-314.bin, modifying qgis.bat the launch the renamed exe, and modifying the part that adds keys to registry to include the version number in some key or value.

Comment: In fact, I have already solved this by copying the text file with the version value during the installation/update process and comparing the test files during launch (qgis.bat) in the folder with installed qgis and in the folder with the distribution. But I was trying to find a more reliable way. But thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

To report here the answer of Zoltan in the comment: running
`qgis-ltr-bin --version` or `qgis-bin --version` should print the version number (since 3.8). It can be run via the OSGeo Shell or in a normal shell window (just provide the full path like `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe --version`).

However on Windows, nothing will be printed on the console if you use the old command line *cmd.exe* ([see this ticket to know more](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44694)). If you use it, you need to pipe the (hidden) output with `qgis-ltr-bin --version > version.txt` to get a file named `version.txt` containing a string similar to `QGIS 3.16.9-Hannover 'Hannover' (9f8d2f79)`.

If instead one use the Windows Powershell, `qgis-ltr-bin --version | echo` will print to the console (hat tip to @nlaan).

For reference, below are all the available commands for `qgis-ltr-bin`/`qgis-bin`:

[image: qgis help menu]

Comment: You can print it to the console with piping to echo:
`qgis-ltr-bin.exe --version | echo`